# Copy/Paste cell value ony after drop-down list trigger

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

When I update a cell via a drop-down list to either “Sold” or “Active” in Column V
I want to Copy and Paste Value of applicable cell from Column W to Column Y

The reason is because I’m using XLookUp in Column W, where the price fluctuates daily.
The idea is to be able to freeze that price in Column Y with just the value at the time Column V changes to either Sold or Active

I've been scouring through tutorials, videos and articles and can't quite seem to get it. Here's a latest snippet I pulled from the internet and was trying to figure it out myself.

```
Sub ReadMarks()
    
    Dim i As Long
    ' Go through the marks columns
    For i = 2 To 11
        ' Check if marks greater than 50
        If Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value > 50 Then
            ' Print student name to the Immediate Window(Ctrl + G)
            Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not put a formula in Col `Y`? For example in `Y2` put this formula. `=IF(OR(V2="Sold",V2="Active"),W2,Y2)`. Note that this formula has a circular reference. So to make it work, click on `File-Option-Formulas` and then check the box  `Enable iterative formulas`. This way your values will remain frozen till the time `V` has `Sold` or `Active`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right click on sheet tab > `View Code` > insert code into sheet module
- When a user modifies any cells in Column V, the following code copies the value from Column W to Column Y in the same row as the changed cell.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column = 22 And (.Value = "Sold" Or .Value = "Active") Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Me.Cells(.Row, "Y").Value = Me.Cells(.Row, "W").Value
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```